# Please help to understand why the python code works like below

Tags: python

I don't know why *result = my_function()* returns only hello there and what's up, and *print(result)* returns only 52.

(Code)

```
def my_function():
    print("hello there")
    print("what's up")
    return 52

print("done")
result = my_function()
print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *What do you think it should do instead? Why*? If you don't have an alternative idea about what should happen, then there is nothing we can explain - it does what it does because that's what the code says should be done. If you have a different idea, then we can possibly explain a misconception.

Comment: Print and return are not the same thing.

Comment: That said: `my_function()` **does not** return either `'hello there'` or `"what's up"`. It returns `52`. That's the point of the code that says `return 52` - `return` means "stop here and return something", and `52` is the thing that gets returned. `print(result)` **does not** return `52`. It returns `None`. Printing things and returning them have *absolutely nothing to do with each other*.

Comment: `print` just show the value at the running time in interpreter to user whereas `return` give the output from the function to functional call.   to whatever you want after function execution stop then use return on that variable/object. and to see the value at any stage of a object use print

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the value being returned from **my_function** to the variable **result**. 
 `print(result)` isnt returning anything, it is simply printing the value that was already returned when you called **my_function**.